# Using Coordinate System in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 2d, space, coordinate

I've been working on a project involving inverse source problem known within the electromagnetic wave field. The problem i have is that ; I have to define 3 points in a 2D space. These points should have a x,y coordinate of course and a value which will define its' current. Like this:

```
A1(2,3)=1
A2(2,-2)=2
and so on.
```

Also i have to define a circle around this and divide it into 200 points. Like the first point would be ; say `R=2 ; B1(2,0) ;B50(0,2);B100(-2,0)` and so on.

Now i really am having a hard time to define a space in MATLAB and circle it. So what i am asking is to help me define a 2D space and do it as the way i described. Thanks for any help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of code may be use. Look at `grid` in the Variable editor.

```
grid = zeros(50, 50);
R = 10;
angles = (1:200)/2/pi;
x = cos(angles)*R;
y = sin(angles)*R;

center = [25 20];

for n=1:length(angles)   
    grid(center(1)+1+round(x(n)), center(2)+1+round(y(n))) = 1;
end
```

You have to define a grid large enough for your need.

Comment: And to see if i did it right how can i plot it? Would using the plot command work? Anyway that was great help thank you.

Comment: And the For loop you included confused me. What does it do exactly? And how can i define a source for example S1 at the coordinate 2,2 and with a value of 3 ?

Comment: The variable `center` contains the coordinates of your center. The `+1` is needed since Matlab array are 1-based. `x` and `y` are the points of your circle (200 points on the trigonometric circle).
If you just want to do verification, a solution is to copy-paste the array in a spreadsheet (Excel for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example that might be of help:

```
%# points
num = 3;
P = [2 3; 2 -2; -1 1];          %# 2D points coords
R = [2.5 3 3];                  %# radii of circles around points

%# compute circle points
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,20)';   %'
unitCircle = [cos(theta) sin(theta)];
C = zeros(numel(theta),2,num);
for i=1:num
    C(:,:,i) = bsxfun(@plus, R(i).*unitCircle, P(i,:));
end

%# prepare plot
xlims = [-6 6]; ylims = [-6 6];
line([xlims nan 0 0],[0 0 nan ylims], ...
    'LineWidth',2, 'Color',[.2 .2 .2])
axis square, grid on
set(gca, 'XLim',xlims, 'YLim',ylims, ...
    'XTick',xlims(1):xlims(2), 'YTick',xlims(1):xlims(2))
title('Cartesian Coordinate System')
xlabel('x-coords'), ylabel('y-coords')

hold on

%# plot centers
plot(P(:,1), P(:,2), ...
    'LineStyle','none', 'Marker','o', 'Color','m')
str = num2str((1:num)','A%d');    %'
text(P(:,1), P(:,2), , str, ...
    'HorizontalAlignment','left', 'VerticalAlignment','bottom')

%# plot circles
clr = lines(num);
h = zeros(num,1);
for i=1:num
    h(i) = plot(C(:,1,i), C(:,2,i), ...
        'LineStyle','-', 'Marker','.', 'Color',clr(i,:));
end
str = num2str((1:num)','Circle %d');    %'
legend(h, str, 'Location','SW')

hold off
```

[image: screenshot]